# mapreduce usecase for employees starting and ending time to find out which employee satying more time

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

INPUT
empmname |logintime|logofftime

shiva|9.30|10.30

prasad|9.35|9.55

shiva|10.40|11.45

shiva|11.55|12.30

shiva|1.40|2.45

shiva|3.40|4.45

prasad|10.10|10.55

prasad|11.35|12.05

prasad|12.45|1.45

prasad|2.35|4.45

prasad|5.35|6.10

ravi|9.00|9.55

ravi|10.00|11.50

ravi|1.05|1.20

ravi|5.00|5.55

requriment:

mapreduce program to find  out which user stayed more time .

Comment: please also mention what you have tried.

Comment: Absolutely Unclear

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a question from an Examination or something, I won't tell you the code, but here's how the logic should look like:

1. Get the data in String, split it on the basis of '|' and get the difference of the start and end time and send it to the reducer
2. At the reducer, add all the "time" corresponding to single employee

As simple as that.

By the way, you should learn to think this way if you want to get ahead with hadoop